# Decomposition and Gridding of a map

Tags: mapping, graph

I am looking for a package to make a graph/grid.
I did slam a map and there is the original screenshot of it. [image]
I would like to have something like the next photo, red squares presenting the cells, and a graph connecting the middle of each cell. [image]

Is there any package that can do it ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I would appreciate if you could suggest me a different forum or a way to dog deep in questions like this one

Comment: I would recommend digging around the [ROS package index](https://index.ros.org/) or seeing if folks on the [ROS Discord](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-the-official-osrf-discord-server/30236) have any thoughts on this.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question here if you get an answer elsewhere, cross links help a lot too (add a link here back to a post somewhere else, and link to this question in your post there).